# Listing files and getting information of a public folder from google drive

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

I created a public folder in google drive. Now i want to access it from my android project. To list files of the folder and to download files from it. But i am not getting any way. Search too many blogs and here in stackoverflow ansers. But none of them is working for me.

I don't need to access users google drive. Its my account google drive where i created a public folder and places files into there.

Please help if anybody have straight forward answer for my use case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to access the Google Drive Files of your Account, But to get to that you can either access the files using a Android native Google Drive application or Google Drive Sponsored Api for accessing User's files (The User and the developer being yourself !). Its either of the two options you have to follow for now, as google hasn't looked into the requirement you wanted. you might leave a comment for your requirement at [google discussions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gs-discussion).